# Intersection between two convex functions with some specific properties

Tags: convex-analysis

> Given two strictly concave, strictly increasing and everywhere derivable functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}^+_0 \to [0,1]$ where $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=1$$ Excluding $x=0$, what is the maximum number of the other intersections between them?

I think $2$ points, but I did not find a good proof of that.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: It seems intuitive. But I don't exclude that a counterexample exists.

Comment: There is always the case $f=g$, which satisfies your assumptions as they are currently written. Beyond this, suppose there is a point $x$ other than $0$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$. Can you construct an example, or derive a contradiction? Perhaps you can consider the problem with $f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ instead; try drawing $f$ and $g$ concave and intersecting somewhere and see what happens.

Comment: Do you want the functions to be continuous at $0$ or it doesn't matter? The current conditions only imply continuity in $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Yes. But River Li has provided a good counterexample, so my conjecture is wrong. Maybe we have to add some other constraints to obtain  an upper bound to the number of intersections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
f(x) &= 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-x}, \\
g(x) &= 1 - \mathrm{e}^{-x} + \frac{1}{4}\mathrm{e}^{-x}\sin x.
\end{align}
We have $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = 1$.
Also, we have, on $[0, \infty)$,
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \mathrm{e}^{-x} > 0, \\
f''(x) &= -\mathrm{e}^{-x} < 0, \\
g'(x) &= \mathrm{e}^{-x} - \frac{1}{4}\mathrm{e}^{-x}\sin x + \frac{1}{4}\mathrm{e}^{-x}\cos x > 0\\
g''(x) &= -\mathrm{e}^{-x}  - \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-x}\cos x < 0.
\end{align}
Thus, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both strictly concave, strictly increasing.

However, $f(x) = g(x)$ for $x = \pi, 2\pi, 3\pi, \cdots$.